# Formula to find matching row value in multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010, formula

I need a formula that would look in columns `Jan`, `Feb` & `Mar` to see if of the three months two months contained a `0`, then in column 5 it would return the word `win`.

```
Store   Jan Feb Mar Outcome
101     0
102     50  0
103     0   100
104     0   0       Win
105     0   0       Win
```

Comment: "to see if tow of the three months two months " Can you clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. (Placed in E2 and copied down)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2,0)=2,"win","")
```

It counts how many zeroes are in columns B-D and if 2 then returns `win`